# Resample (spatially-average) DataArray / raster to match the grid of another DataArray in Python

Tags: python, gis, raster, python-xarray, resampling

I would like to resample a DataArray / raster object to exactly match the spatial grid of another DataArray / raster object. In particular, the operation I want to perform is a spatial averaging to reduce the spatial resolution of the DataArray / raster object.

Is it possible to do this using xarray, rasterio, or any other tool?

PS. I am not sure 'resampling' is the correct word to use here.

Comment: Can you give us some sample code of anything you've tried already?

Comment: Thanks @EliotK, I found a solution: rioxarray has a method 'reproject_match' that does exactly what I described above. 

For more info: https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/rioxarray.html?highlight=write_crs#rioxarray.raster_array.RasterArray.reproject_match

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

rioxarray has the method 'reproject_match', which does exactly what I describe above.

For more info: https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/rioxarray.html?highlight=write_crs#rioxarray.raster_array.RasterArray.reproject_match